# What do the 'Common', 'JVM', 'JS', and 'JVM' tags indicate in the kotlin docs?

Tags: kotlin

At the top of each class in the docs, for example on the [`Number` class](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html) these 4 tags exist at the top and each function has one or more of the tags.

What do they indicate?

Answer (score 2):

These are the target platforms where the corresponding standard library declarations are available. *Common* means that a declaration may be used in code shared between all platforms in [Kotlin Multiplatform projects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html).

If a declaration is not available on some platform, like [`readLine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) (JVM and Native only, but no JS), you won't be able to compile its usage for that specific platform.